# Installing Chrome Dev Tools in Eclipse - Debug Configurations missing config

Tags: eclipse, google-chrome-devtools

I followed the installation here: http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/wiki/DebuggerTutorial

I installed them on both machines, and it works on one machine (running win7) but not the other (running Win XP). Not working means everything looks fine, until you look into the Debug Configurations, you won't see the "Chromium JavaScript" et al. My colleague's Win XP machine works fine. Is it just simple installation only, I have tried with Eclipse Indigo SR1 and SR2, both doesn't work on my machine.

Is it because of the machine? Why?

Comment: I submitted an issue. This seems reproducible. http://code.google.com/p/chromedevtools/issues/detail?id=72

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have a wrong Java version. ChromeDevTools requires 1.6.

You can check it from Eclipse -> Help -> About Eclipse SDK -> Installation Details -> Configuration, a property "java.vm.version"

Unfortunately Eclipse only silently outputs error to console once per installation in this case.